# CPLEX won't display decision variables after successful solution

Tags: optimization, cplex, mixed-integer-programming, integer-programming

I set up a code for a course scheduling optimization problem using IBM CPLEX.
The decision variable is `dvar boolean x[course][roomtype][timeslot];`, where x is 1 if the course takes place in a room type r during timeslot t.

The model has worked perfectly fine and is feasible for all instances and scenarios I tried it on. Now, for a new scenario, I increased the number of timeslots from 46 to 240, which increased the overall number of decision variables to over 2 million instead of around 300,000.

Now, I can still run the model and after slightly longer run time I get an optimal solution. Yet, the process I had for analysis before was displaying the decision variables, sorting for the ones with the value of 1 and copying and pasting them into Excel for further analysis.

This is now not possible anymore as CPLEX won't respond for a very long time and then does not let me do anything anymore from that point onwards ([Limited extent of decision variable display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeRZK.png)). I have to close the program and start again.

I assumed the problem was the RAM or overall memory, so I opted for Cloud Services of my university. But even having 128GB of RAM, 12 cores and 500 GB of memory at hand was not sufficient and the performance is exactly the same as with my own private laptop.

Any suggestions on what could be the problem or how to export the solution anyway?

Are there variable limits with CPLEX that would make this impossible to solve?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

indeed displaying huge matrixes can freeze the IDE.

You wrote:

> Now, I can still run the model and after slightly longer run time I
> get an optimal solution. Yet, the process I had for analysis before
> was displaying the decision variables, sorting for the ones with the
> value of 1 and copying and pasting them into Excel for further
> analysis.

You should do that with SheetWrite.
First you build a set of the ones with value 1 and then you export with SheetWrite.

In [Excel, Rocket science and optimization](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/excel-rocket-science-optimization-alex-fleischer/)

[image: Excel, Rocket science and optimization]

.mod

```
range A=1..2;
range B=1..3;
range C=1..4;


dvar int X[A][B][C];

subject to
{
forall(a in A,b in B,c in C) X[a][b][c]==a*b*c;
}

tuple someTuple{
int a;
int b;
int c;
int value;
};


{someTuple} someSet = {<i,j,k,X[i][j][k]> | i in A, j in B, k in C:X[i][j][k]==1};
```

.dat

```
SheetConnection sheet("write3Darray.xlsx");

    someSet to SheetWrite(sheet,"A1:D24");
```